# Swift 2 Protocol Extensions and Conformance for Objective-C Types

Tags: objective-c, swift, protocol-extension

I have a setup like this:

```
@interface Model: NSManagedObject
...
@end
```

And a Swift protocol like this:

```
@objc protocol Syncable {
    var uploadURL: String { get }
    var uploadParams: [String: AnyObject]? { get }
    func updateSyncState() throws
}

extension Syncable where Self: NSManagedObject {
    func updateSyncState() throws {
        ... /* default implementation */ ...
    }
}
```

In a new Swift file, I try to do this:

```
extension Model: Syncable {
    var uploadURL: String {
        return "a url"
    }
    var uploadParams: [String: AnyObject]? {
        return [:]
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error, with Xcode saying "type 'Model' does not conform to protocol 'Syncable'". Xcode also keeps suggesting that I put an `@objc` somewhere in my extension but it can't seem to figure out where it should go.

Is what I'm doing impossible? (It seems to work under simple conditions in a playground - but with my Objective-C class being written in Swift, obviously).

If it is impossible, help in understanding why would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the attempt to mix Objective-C and Swift features. This pure Swift code compiles just fine (note that I've eliminated NSManagedObject from the story, as it has nothing to do with the issue):

```
class MyManagedObject {}

class Model: MyManagedObject {}

protocol Syncable {
    var uploadURL: String { get }
    var uploadParams: [String: AnyObject]? { get }
    func updateSyncState()
}

extension Syncable where Self: MyManagedObject {
    func updateSyncState() {
    }
}

extension Model: Syncable {
    var uploadURL: String {
        return "a url"
    }
    var uploadParams: [String: AnyObject]? {
        return [:]
    }
}
```

That's because Swift knows what a protocol extension is. But Objective-C doesn't! So as soon as you say `@objc protocol` you move the protocol into the Objective-C world, and the protocol extension has no effect - and thus Model doesn't conform, as it has no `updateSyncState` implementation.

Comment: Well... you are right. But interesting thing is that in my playground, I have something very similar to what you posted, but my protocol *does* have the `@objc`, and things still work.

Comment: Well, a playground is not an app. It's really misleading to test certain stuff in a playground. I always test in a real app.